# Updating ldap from java

Tags: java, windows, linux, ldap

I know that java offers a set of apis to contact an LDAP server, and a process could contact LDAP server by providing credentials, but I always thought that to **update**
the LDAP besides a user name and password, the PC contacting LDAP should be joined in the windows domain.

Is assumption this wrong?

Comment: windows' active directory is just an (extended) implementation of LDAP; LDAP existed before AD (rfc of ldapv2 is mid '90s if i remember correctly), and will probably survive after it

Comment: @guido:But I am asking about being able to **update** from a non Windows client

Comment: that depends uniquely on the authorization level of the user used for connection. windows or no windows is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That assumption is indeed wrong.

LDAP is not a Windows-specific technology. All you need in order to update directory data is the ability to connect to the appropriate port (389 for unencrypted or TLS-encrypted connections, or 636 for SSL-encrypted connections) and bind to the LDAP server using the credentials of a user that has sufficient access to modify the attributes you have in mind.

Comment: Ok, but what does this mean?That Windows implementation do not impose such a restriction for updating LDAP?

Comment: You asked if the client contacting the LDAP server had to be joined to the Windows domain. The answer is no. Where I work we have an Active Directory server, and I have written PHP code that runs on a Linux server, connects to the AD server via LDAP/SSL, performs an LDAP bind using an administrative user's credentials, and then updates another user's password. The Linux server, of course, is NOT joined to the Windows domain.

Comment: I asked if the client not belonging to the domain could do **update** (also with emphasis in OP).That it can bind I know.I was asking if it could **update** the LDAP registry/server

Comment: Yes, if the bind is done using the credentials of a user that has sufficient access to modify (or update), a client that does not belong to the Windows domain can indeed update the LDAP data. As I said above, I have code that updates a user's password with a new one. If this does not answer your question, then perhaps it would help if you could explain exactly what you mean by "update".